# Validación de solo Strings. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

estoy aprendiendo javascript.
Hay alguna funcion que valide solamente strings textos?
Ejemplo tengo el siguiente codigo que funciona bien, solo acepta NUMEROS

```
var edad= document.querySelector("#edad").value;    //aqui jala el valor que tiene le ID en el HTML
if( isNaN(edad)==false){ 
alert("el nombre no es valido");
}
```

Pero en caso de querer hacer lo mismo con una cadena de texto como lo haría? Hay alguna funcion contraria al isNaN?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si bien ya te han comentado lo más recomendable es realizar una expresión regular, pero si no quieres complicarte la vida la respuesta está en tu propio código te muestro un ejemplo con tu propio código:

```
var edad= document.querySelector("#edad").value

//Verificamos si lo que se ingresa es un numero
if(isNaN(edad)){ 
 //Código a realizar
}

/*Si niegas todo ese if
Estarías diciendo si NO es un numero lo que ingresó el usuario nota el signo ! Al inicio del if con eso niegas toda la expresión*/

if(!isNaN(edad)){ 
 //Código a realizar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola jose el operador `typeof` devuelve una cadena indicando el tipo de valor que estas evaluando , proba usarla , espero que te sirva

```
var edad= document.querySelector("#edad").value;    //aqui jala el valor que tiene le 
ID en el HTML
if( typeof edad == 'string'){ 
alert("esto es una cadena/string");
}
```

Comment: `5 ` sería un string en este caso, y puede que eso no sea un valor correcto para el AP. Creo que en este caso haría falta usar un regex para realizar el filtrado de manera correcta.

Comment: Hola facu
intenté con el typeof como indicas. Si funciona-. Pero aunque ingrese texto(correcto) o numero ,. Me manda la alerta del if.  Es decir: ponga texto o numero ejecuta el if con el alert

Comment: perfecto jose , entonces si , tendrias que ir con la expresion regular !

Answer (score 0):

Como te comentaba mas arriba lo mas conveniente sería validar el dato ingresado [contra un regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Hoja_de_referencia), de esta forma:

declaro la variable y su valor:

```
let valorX = 10;
```

Construyo la regex de esta forma:

```
/[A-Za-z]/.test(valor)// false
```

Como salida tendré `false`, aún poniendo el 10 entre comillas pues el 10 o "10" no estarían coincidiendo con los valores pasados dentro de los corchetes.

Answer (score 0):

este codigo funciona correctamente:

```
var edad= document.querySelector("#edad").value;
//verificamos si el valor enviado es NaN
if(isNaN(adad)){
  // codigo si es NaN
}else{
  // si no es NaN
}
```